# \listoffigures not generating

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having an issue with `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. They are not generating.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\linespread{1.6}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{abstract}

\chapter*{Dedication}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}


\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\input{Chapters/Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

and this is how I do my figures:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/P66614NCN2.jpg}
\caption[EAN sample]{EAN after some stuff.}
\label{fig:P66614NCN2}
\end{figure}
```

But for whatever reason, my list of figures and list of tables remains blank. Can't find anything about how to resolve this. Any help?

Here is my file long:

```
*File List*
report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
utf8.def    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
hyphenat.sty    2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities
tocbibind.sty    2010/10/13 v1.5k extra ToC listings
fancyhdr.sty    
appendix.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2b extra appendix facilities
array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: I guess technically I tried twice since I have ad issues with things not coming together after one compile. Will try now and report back. Thanks! ------ just checked and it did not work.

Comment: Hm, your code works fine here. I removed `\input{abstract}` and the `\includegraphics` (as I don't have any of the files), but I get *EAN sample* in the list of figures, as expected. Silly question, but you're not by any chance somehow deleting/moving the auxiliary files (`.lot`,`.lof`) between compilation runs are you?

Comment: No I am not deleting any files. That's so weird that you are getting it to work. Is it possible it is because I am inputting the files that contain my figures and that's why it isn't listing them?

Comment: No, that shouldn't (doesn't) matter. Can you describe in more detail the steps you take to produce a PDF?

Answer (score 3):

Because we do not have your used image and the other files you `\input`ed I changed your given code snippets to a compilable MWE.  With my current version of MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile the MWE without errors.  After the third compile run one will see the table of contents, the list of figures (but not list of tables, because I did not add one).

With the command `\listfiles` I added you get an list of used packages and version numbers at the end of the `log` file.  Please compare this list with mine.

MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\linespread{1.6}
%\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{gensymb} % <========================= causes two warnings!
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % <============================= Why?
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Dedication}
\chapter*{Acknowledgment}

\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/P66614NCN2.jpg}
  \caption[EAN sample]{EAN after some stuff.}
  \label{fig:P66614NCN2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

and my list of used packages and version numbers:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
hyphenat.sty    2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities
tocbibind.sty    2010/10/13 v1.5k extra ToC listings
fancyhdr.sty    2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
appendix.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2b extra appendix facilities
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 ***********

 )
```

Comment: It seems like a few of my packages are an older version. You think that's enough to cause the issue? ... I also tried making a new latex document and copy and pasting the code with the graphix code and still nothing.

Comment: I copied your code and it worked. I thought maybe it was the gensymb package that was causing the issue, but commenting that out of my main file didn't generate a list of figures.

Comment: Also I use gensymb to allow me to use \degree to make a degree symbol

Comment: Ok i finally figured out the one line that was messing everything up:  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}                            As soon as I took that out things are working now.